# How can you solve this momentum puzzle?

Tags: portal-2

I am in the 1976 version of the Aperture facility and I am stuck on this one momentum challenge.  When you first enter it looks like this:
[image]

You are supposed to launch yourself from here
[image]

To that staircase
[image]

But the problem is that there are no portal surfaces on the ground anywhere around here and you cant use gels.  If you know how to solve this please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the piston momentum hallway from the area before to propel yourself across the gap.